# how to show all method and data when the object not has "__iter__" function in python

Tags: python, methods, show, dir

i find a way :

(1):the dir(object) is :

```
a="['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__str__', '__weakref__', '_errors', '_fields', '_prefix', '_unbound_fields', 'confirm', 'data', 'email', 'errors', 'password', 'populate_obj', 'process', 'username', 'validate']"
```

(2):

```
b=eval(a)
```

(3)and it became a list of all method :

```
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__str__', '__weakref__', '_errors', '_fields', '_prefix', '_unbound_fields', 'confirm', 'data', 'email', 'errors', 'password', 'populate_obj', 'process', 'username', 'validate']
```

(3)then  show the object's method,and all code is  :

```
s=''
a=eval(str(dir(object)))
for i in a:
    s+=str(i)+':'+str(object[i])

print s
```

but it show error :

```
KeyError: '__class__'
```

so how to make my code running .

thanks

Comment: `dir` returns a list, not a string.  You're converting it to a string, then evaling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = ''.join('%s: %s' % (a, getattr(o, a)) for a in dir(o))
```

- `dir` lists all attributes
- the `for ... in` creates a generator which returns each attribute name
- the `getattr` retrieves the value of the attribute for the object
- the `%` interpolates those values into a string
- the `''.join` concatenates all the strings into a single one

Answer (score 2):

```
s += str(i)+':'+str(getattr(object, i))
```